# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes)

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a footer for html page using "include" but i am getting error. I am new to PHP so i don't know any other solution. Even i have tried similar possibilities, but still it is not working..

This is the error which i have got

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're exhausting your memory. You need to figure out  what is causing the script to run out of memory. What is in that footer.php file?

Comment: My second image shows footer.php file

Comment: Yeah Steve's solution should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second image is your footer file then it is including itself. That means when it runs it will infinately loop, including itself over and over again until the memory limit is reached.

Remove `include("footer.php");` from footer.php!